# Possible to join Rails Action Text Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Using Rails 6 rc1, I'm doing a query on a model called 'Job'.

**Job Model (job.rb):**

```
has_rich_text :description
belongs_to :company, dependent: :destroy, required: false

def self.search(query)  
  joins(:company, :description)
  .where.not(has_ended: true)
  .where("jobs.title ILIKE ?", query)
  .where("jobs.description ILIKE ?", query)
  .where("companies.name ~* ?", "^#{query}") # https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-matching.html
end
```

That's exactly what I have. So far my issue is with the inclusion of `has_rich_text`. The error, when replicated in the rails console `Job.joins(:description)`:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (Association named 'description' was not found on Job; perhaps you misspelled it?

When searching "hight and low", I could not find any documentation on this level of query. I havent tried `scope` [mentioned here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: If the `description` is an attribute you cant *joins* it. You can join only tables. Remove `:description` from `joins(:company, :description)`.

Comment: Hi. Correct. But.... how do I access Action Text with my query?

Answer (score 3):

### There actually already is a has_one relation defined by the has_rich_text method

[github.com/rails/.../actiontext/lib/action_text/attribute.rb Line 37](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f2b69d80ab9e81d2b3cc526aa5ad87e432b66081/actiontext/lib/action_text/attribute.rb#L37)

```rb
# name on the next two lines is a reference to what you called your rich_text.
has_one :"rich_text_#{name}",
  -> { where(name: name) },
  class_name: "ActionText::RichText",
  as: :record,
  inverse_of: :record,
  autosave: true,
  dependent: :destroy
```

So in your case, you'd want to join with rich_text_description

---

#### For searching through multiple rich_texts, you can add a has_many rich_texts relation.

```rb
has_many :rich_texts,
  class_name: "ActionText::RichText",
  as: :record,
  inverse_of: :record,
  autosave: true,
  dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can! I've posted the menthod on the [Rails Github page](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36267) I've used but need to know if there is a better way.

Comment: "joins(:rich_title) # This will never work, which is understandable" you were pretty close there. It would be joins(:rich_text_rich_title)

Answer (score 0):

I used inner join

model relation is 1:1 and article : action_text_rich_text

in Article model

```
scope :search, -> (name) { joins("INNER JOIN action_text_rich_texts ON action_text_rich_texts.record_id = articles.id").where("action_text_rich_texts.body LIKE ? or articles.title like ?", "%#{name}%", "%#{name}%") }
```